# How to tell aptitude to automatically install missing packages instead of removing ones to statisfy dependencies?

Tags: debian, aptitude

I'm creating a live CD with Skype using live-build. During the build process I run the following script:

```
# Download the Skype package suitable for Squeeze
wget --continue -O skype-install.deb \
    http://download.skype.com/linux/skype-debian_4.0.0.7-1_i386.deb
# Install the package.
dpkg -i --force-architecture --no-debsig skype-install.deb || true
# Fix missing dependencies
aptitude -f install
```

The problem is that `aptitude -f install` suggest to remove Skype instead of installing the missing libraries. I have to tell it interactively to prefer the second solution. Can I tell somehow on the command line? Ideally I'd like to run it unattended like

```
aptitude -y --some-flag-to-ensure-no-removals -f install
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be possible to use aptitude's `--safe-resolver` option to do what you want. Quoting the man page for aptitude 0.6.8.2:

> This resolver attempts to preserve as many of your choices as possible; **it will never remove a package** or install a version of a package other than the package's default candidate version.

To do it globally, set `Aptitude::Always-Use-Safe-Resolver` to `true`.